# Irreducible $f\in F[x]$ has a root in $F[x]/\langle f \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots

Let $F$ be a field and let $f\in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Prove that $f$ has a root in $K:=F[x]/\langle f \rangle$.

I don't have any start nor attampt to show. I just mention that $K\cong F(c)$ where $c$ is some root of $f$.

Comment: What is $f([X])$?

Comment: Denote $\xi$ the congruence class of the indeterminate $X$.

Comment: $f([x])=\sum a_k[x]^k=\sum a_k(x+f(x))^k=\sum a_k(x^k+f(x))=\sum a_k x^k+\sum a_k f(x)=f(x)+(a_0+...a_n)f(x)=f(x)+f(x)=f(x)=\bar{0}$. Thanks @Thorgott

Comment: If you haven't gotten it yet, do you mean that $\langle f \rangle$ is the ideal generated by $f$?

Comment: I've understand the answer from the first comment. Thanks